# Which .net framework version will a library run in

Tags: c#, .net

If i have a library which is compiled in .NET 4 and reference it from a .net 4.5 executable which version of the framework will operations defined in the library execute against?

I have a cli app which is built in .net 4.5 and references both .net 4 and .net 4.5 projects and im wondering if both will use the same version of the ADO.net components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will both run in the same CLR (4.5 in this case).

With .NET <=3.5, you could have cases where multiple versions of the same assembly will be loaded (so, it could happen that ADO.NET will load version 4.0 and also load 4.5 in the same app domain). As far as I know, they either eliminated that with CLR 4.0 (or at least made it happen way less).

Edit: BTW - there's a difference between the CLR (the runtime running your code) and the versions of the assemblies being loaded.

The version of the CLR governs the capabilities of the process - what it can do, which versions of assemblies it can load. For example,, CLR 4.5 can load pretty much all assemblies (1.0 -> 4.5). They will all run under the 4.5 CLR. On top of that, you cannot run two versions of the CLR from the same compat band in the same process. CLR 4.5 and 4.0 both are considered the same compat band, so either one or the other will load. CLR 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 are all considered in the same compat band, so only one of them can load. You can, however, load CLR 3.5 and CLR 4.5 at the same time.

Comment: I thought that if you reference an assembly that targeted a different framework you got compilation errors.

Comment: Only if there's a binary break (which are few and far between) or if you are trying to reference an assembly targetting a more advanced CLR version (so, a 2.0 assembly referencing a 4.0 assembly will break. The opposite will not)

Comment: I think it will break also if you a specifying a different version of the assembly. For example, you have assembly build in 4.0 and you specified in the web.config (or wherever it is loaded from) 3.5

Comment: So in my case if i load up my .net 4 assembly with my .net 4.5 process it will load under the 4.5 CLR which means it will use the 4.5 versions of System.Data?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: Well, for the most part that is what will happen, however, a few things to keep in mind... 1. There may not be a v4.5 of an assembly. Some assemblies keep their initial versions (there are a few assemblies that are shipping with 3.5 that are marked as 2.0). 2. If you somehow force the 4.0 version to load first (by using an explicit load call, or by using Web.Config, then that is going to be the one loaded. All other things being equal, yes, the 4.5 version will be loaded.